# how to run python script in cmd

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm

I wrote a small project to render video in the console. I used PyCharm, and if I run the code in it everything works as it should, but how do I run the file so that the result is displayed on the console?

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import os

vid = cv.VideoCapture('badapple.mp4')
input()
ret, frame = vid.read()
a = frame.shape[0] / 50
b = frame.shape[1]//a*2
b = "mode con cols="+str(int(b))+" lines=50"
os.system(b)
while 1:
    cons_frame = ''
    ret, frame = vid.read()

    new_frame1 = cv.resize(frame, (int(frame.shape[1]//a*2), 50), interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)

    cv.imshow('title', frame)
    new_frame = cv.cvtColor(new_frame1, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    for i in new_frame:
        for j in i:
            if j[2] < 25:
                cons_frame = cons_frame + ' '
            elif j[2] < 50:
                cons_frame = cons_frame + '.'
            elif j[2] < 75:
                cons_frame = cons_frame + '-'
            elif j[2] < 100:
                cons_frame = cons_frame + ':'
            elif j[2] < 125:
                cons_frame = cons_frame + '='
            elif j[2] < 150:
                cons_frame = cons_frame + '+'
            elif j[2] < 175:
                cons_frame = cons_frame + 'x'
            elif j[2] < 200:
                cons_frame = cons_frame + '#'
            elif j[2] < 225:
                cons_frame = cons_frame + '%'
            else:
                cons_frame = cons_frame + '@'
    print(cons_frame, flush=True)

    if cv.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('d'):
        break

vid.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: what's the output when you run 
py3 script.py ?

Comment: what output exactly you want to show on console/cmd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your usage of `mode con`, you must be on Windows. Assuming you have Python installed correctly, it should be as simple as opening up `cmd.exe`, navigating to your project's .py file, and typing
`python badapple.py`, or whatever the script's filename is.

Comment: I think author not talking about how to run from cmd...He is talking about printing results to cmd?

Comment: thx, but now the console output "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'". This is due to the fact that the libraries were installed through PyCharm, right?

Comment: @JeNyaBright It could also be the case that PyCharm doesn't see the same Python install as Windows does for some reason. Regardless, running
`pip install opencv-python` and `pip install numpy` should fix that issue.